# Can't install Cordova, and npm failing to work on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, npm-install

So I am trying to install stuff using npm on my Windows 10 powered machine. I am encountering an error, and it turns out that maybe node package manager ([`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/)) is not working.

I tried using the NodeJS shell (or terminal), and the Git Shell too. This is what I came across:

[image]
From NodeJS

[image]
From Git Shell

I am trying to install `Cordova` and `Ionic`, and would really appreciate a solution that achieves the installation, better yet, that fixes the problems I am having with `npm`.

Comment: Try to install a missing module separately and see if there are any errors related to installation of that module in Windows `npm install github-url-from-git`